# Integrating Estimote UWB SDK in Android Studio project for beacon detection and 3D sound playback

Tags: android, maven, beacon, estimote, uwb

I recently obtained the Estimote UWB SDK for Android and I'm trying to integrate it into my Android Studio project. The SDK folder contains the following files: uwb-sdk-1.0.0-rc1.aar, uwb-sdk-1.0.0-rc1.pom, and maven-metadata.xml. My goal is to build an app that can detect beacons using the Estimote UWB SDK and play 3D sounds when the device gets close to them.

I have tried to include these files in my project, but I encountered a sync failure in my build.gradle file. I'm unsure about the correct location to place these files within my Android Studio project, and how to properly configure the dependencies and build process.

How to correctly integrate the Estimote UWB SDK into an Android Studio project? Specifically, I would appreciate assistance with the following:

1. The correct location to place the Estimote UWB SDK files (uwb-sdk-1.0.0-rc1.aar, uwb-sdk-1.0.0-rc1.pom, and maven-metadata.xml) within my Android Studio project structure. and where to paste this code snippet

   ```
    allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://estimote.jfrog.io/artifactory/android-proximity-sdk"
        }

    }
   ```

   }

[image]

2. How to properly configure the build.gradle file to include the Estimote UWB SDK as a dependency?
3. Any additional steps or considerations I need to be aware of to successfully use the Estimote UWB SDK for beacon detection and 3D sound playback?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still looking for the answer, but after adding the maven repository as a source, you have to add the dependency as you usually would to your `build.gradle`

`implementation 'com.estimote:uwb-sdk:1.0.0-rc5'`

You can browse the repository and look for the artifact id and latest version.